# Python Error: 'finalStore' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I'm working with Inheritance in python but i'm getting an error i don't know how to fix, 'finalStore' object has no attribute 'marone'. I get this when i try create an object.

```
from ClassFile import studStore

class finalStore (studStore):

    grandAve = 0
    numStu = 0

    def __init__(self, name, marone, martwo, marthree, marfour, corone, cortwo, corthree, corfour):
        studStore.__init__(self, name, marone, martwo, marthree, marfour)
        self.corone = corone
        self.cortwo = cortwo
        self.corthree = corthree
        self.corfour = corfour
        finalStore.numStu += 1
        self.holder = finalStore.numStu
        self.average = (marone + martwo + marthree + marfour)/4
        finalStore.grandAve += self.average
        self.storit = finalStore.grandAve
```

My initializing for the child class

```
class studStore:

    def __init__(self, name, marone, martwo, marthree, marfour):
        self.newname = name
        self.Ave = 0
        self.marone = marone
        self.martwo = martwo
        self.marthree = marthree
        self.marfour = marfour
```

And the initializing for the parent class. My main line is just a loop where i create multiple objects for but it errors on this line:

```
listIn.append(finalStore(name, gradeone, gradetwo, gradethree, gradefour, courseOne, courseTwo, courseThree, courseFour))
```

I'm not sure what the error is but I have a similar program that works, I'm just not using the from * import *

I'm outputting it like this

```
for i in range (0,len(listIn)):
    print(str(listIn[i].returnName()).ljust(20," "), end = " ")
    print(str(listIn[i].returnOne()).ljust(20, " "))
    print(str(listIn[i].returnTwo()).ljust(20, " "))
    print(str(listIn[i].returnThree()).ljust(20, " "))
    print(str(listIn[i].returnFour()).ljust(20, " "))
```

Comment: Could you post the actual output of the error?

Comment: "finalStore" object has no attribute "marone"

Comment: Isn't there a stack trace or something that is being printed to your console?  If there is, you should add that to your post.

Comment: The stack trace is the entire output where it is saying you have an error. If you post that then it helps everyone see the entire problem. Sometimes what you think is wrong is actually caused by something else and the stack trace would help reveal that information. What you added was more code which is ok, but it isn't the stack trace that @Haz was asking for.

Comment: Using the code posted, I can access the `marone` attribute of a `finalStore` object. I assume `returnOne()` is the method that tries to access it; what does that code look like?

Comment: @chepner I was thinking the same thing, but he says the error is at initialization time. So either he is wrong, or there is something else going on that a stack trace would reveal. I'm not sure which. Also, yes I was able to copy and paste the code into the interpreter and it all worked for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to the super class's init function is incorrect.  Here is how you should do it:

```
class finalStore(studStore):

    def __init__(self, name, ...):
        super(finalStore, self).__init__(name, marone, ...)
```

Comment: It's not incorrect to call the parent class's `__init__` method that way. Using `super` just guarantees that the `__init__` method of the next class in the method resolution order (which may not actually be `studStore`) is called.